# How to delete border-bottom in kendo grid selected row

Tags: javascript, html, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have grid with kendo when i changed selected row background-color but when i selected row it has also shows me border-bottom as in image

[image: kendo grid selected row with border bottom]

I want to delete that blue line.Also i tried the css like this but not worked.

```
.k-grid .k-state-selected tr {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the Kendo Grid's page on grid selection, it looks like it is the row (`tr`) which has the class `k-state-selected`.

The above CSS selector that you've attempted to use says that the element you're trying to style is a `tr` tag that is an *ancestor* of the element with the class `k-state-selected`.

This is not true as the row itself is what has that class. You can fix it like so:

```
.k-grid tr.k-state-selected {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: You extremely right :) i missed on template css folder is smashed my css so i deleted that and solved problem!!